# Sorting Posts with meta value not working

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, meta-value

I want to retrieve most popular posts based on 'view_count' meta value, the below code doesn't seem to work, I am getting some random posts, where am I doing it wrong?

```
<?php 
   $mostpopular_args=array(
       'post_type'          => 'post',
       'orderby'            => 'meta_value_num',
       'meta_key'           => 'view_count',
       'posts_per_page'     => '10',
   );
?>
<?php $mostpopular_pick = new WP_Query($mostpopular_args); ?>
<?php if($mostpopular_pick->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while($mostpopular_pick->have_posts()): $mostpopular_pick->the_post(); ?>
<article class="widget-article">
   <a href ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <div class="widget-article-thumb">
         <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
         <?php $page_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'featuredsmall'); ?>
         <img src="<?php echo $page_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="" /> 
         <?php } ?>
      </div>
   </a>
   <div class="widget-content-wrapper">
      <h3 class="widget-article-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
   </div>
</article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this is code for updating the view count in single.php

```
<?php $count = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'view_count',true);?>
<?php update_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'view_count',$count+1,$count); ?>
```

Should I reset query some where?

**Update:** Here is my single.php code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
     <div class="main-content col-md-8" role="main">
        <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php $count = (int) get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'view_count',true);?>
            <?php update_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'view_count',$count+1,$count); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'article'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div> <!-- end main-content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And article.php code,

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <!-- Article header -->
    <header class="entry-header"> 
        <?php if(is_single()): ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else: ?>
            <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php 
                // Get the date.
                echo '<div class="meta-date"> ' . get_the_date() . ' </div>';
            ?>

            <div class="meta-author">
                <div class="author-avatar">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    // Get the post author.
                    printf(
                        '<div class="meta-author"><a href="%1$s" rel="author">%2$s</a></div>',
                        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
                        get_the_author()
                    );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header> <!-- end entry-header -->
    <div class="shares-and-views">
        <div class="shares clearfix">
            <div aria-hidden="true" class="bigshare icon icon-share-alt"></div>
            <?php $fb_share_count = (int) get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'cb_fb_share_count',true); ?>
            <?php $tweet_share_count = (int) get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'cb_tweet_share_count',true); ?>
            <?php $total_count = $fb_share_count + $tweet_share_count; ?>

            <div class="cb-share-count"><?php echo $total_count; ?></div>
            <?php do_action("mashshare"); ?>    
        </div>
        <div class="view-count" class="pull-right">
            <span class="icon icon-eye2" style="margin-left:10px" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="share-text">
                    <strong><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'view_count',true); ?></strong>
                            VIEWS
            </span>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <a href ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="article-thumb">
            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
             <?php $page_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'featuredbig'); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $page_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="" />  
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </a>
    <!-- Article content -->
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <?php if ( is_single() ):?>
                <div id="single-page-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                 <?php the_tags(); ?> 
                <?php //comments_template(); ?>
                <?php 
                     $include_categores = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID());
                     $post_not_in = array();
                     $post_not_in[] = get_the_ID();
                     $related_args=array(
                        'post_type'         => 'post',
                        'post__not_in'      => $post_not_in,
                        'category__in'      => $include_categores,
                        'posts_per_page'    => '10',
                     );
                     $related_posts = new WP_Query($related_args);
                ?>
                <div class="related-articles">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h3 class="related-title"><?php _e('Related Articles','patrika');?></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php while($related_posts->have_posts()): $related_posts->the_post(); ?>
                            <article class="related-article col-sm-6">
                                <a href ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="related-article-thumb">
                                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
                                       <?php $page_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'featuredsmall'); ?>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $page_thumb[0]; ?>" alt="" />  
                                       <?php } ?>
                                     </div>
                                </a>
                                <h4 class="related-article-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                <!--<div class="only-count">
                                    <div class="icon icon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[mashshare shares="true" buttons="false"]'); ?>
                                    <div class="share-text">SHARES</div>
                                </div>-->
                            </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end entry-content -->

    <!-- Article footer -->
    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php 
            // If we have a single page and the author bio exists, display it
            if ( is_single() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) ) {
                echo '<h2>' . __( 'Written by ', 'alpha' ) . get_the_author() . '</h2>';
                echo '<p>' . the_author_meta( 'description' ) . '</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </footer> <!-- end entry-footer -->
</article>
```

Comment: add the output of `$mostpopular_pick->request` after the query is run to your question. this is the SQL query being sent to the database and should give you a hint as to why it's not working.

Comment: Mind = Blown,**Here is the output:**
string(383) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'view_count' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 2".

I just queried 2 posts, but its returning 4 and it is ordering by 'menu_order' instead of 'meta_value_num'. Why?

Comment: Thank you @Milo :). Issue resolved. Post Types Order is altering the query. Now everything is working as expected :)